# Getting the arguments passed to a executable using wmic

Tags: wmic, command-line-arguments

I am trying to get commandline arguments of an executable which was launched by another program.

I tried the command mentioned in [this](https://serverfault.com/a/323821) answer, but I can't understand the syntax :(

I am trying to get the commandline arguments of an process, I have the PID & the process name, In this case I am trying get arguments of an ping command which I am using to test the command...

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
wmic process where "name='ping.exe'" get commandline /format:list
```

Or if you prefer to query by PID:

```
wmic process where "processid='NNNN'" get commandline /format:list
```

`wmic` uses a query language called WQL, which is similar to SQL.  You can do wildcard stuff like `wmic process where "name like 'ping%'" get commandline` (but be sure to double the `%%` within a batch script), vary the output style (list, csv, even html), and other magic.  See `wmic /?` from a command line for more info.

---

If you want to capture the output of any command to a variable, use a `for /f` loop.  `help for` in a cmd console for more info.  Try this in a cmd console:

```
for /f "delims=" %I in ('wmic process where "name='ping.exe'" get commandline /format:list ^| find "="') do set "%I"
```

You'll notice something very odd indeed.  The output of that command will be similar to this:

> **" \Users\username>set "CommandLine=ping  -n 60 localhost**

The closing quotation mark gets printed at the *beginning* of the line!  Isn't that weird?  That's because WMI query results are encoded in UCS-2 LE, not ANSI.

One workaround I like to use is to use `/format:csv` and add a disposable column to the query.

From within a batch script:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (
    'wmic process where "name='ping.exe'" get commandline^,status /format:csv'
) do set "commandline=%%I"
```

... and that way you won't capture any invisible treachery to your variable.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! This is what I was looking for :)