# Get command line of another process in .NET Core

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, process, .net-core

The following code throws an `InvalidOperationException`: "*Process was not started by this object, so requested information cannot be determined*" when accessing the `StartInfo` property.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProcArgs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("svchost").FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(process.StartInfo.Arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

So how does one get the command line of another already running process in .NET Core 2.2 (Windows)?

Comment: Are you running as Administrator?

Comment: Running it as administrator doesn't help.

Comment: [How do I get the command line of another process?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923): 'the string is merely a "preinitialized variable", a process could in principle (and many do in practice, although usually inadvertently) write to the memory that holds the command line, in which case, if you go snooping around for it, you'll see the modified command line. There is no secret hiding place where the kernel keeps the "real original command line," any more than there is a secret hiding place where the C compiler keeps the "real original parameters to a function."

Comment: With Windows Compatibility Pack you should be able to run WMI queries to get such. Examples like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607802/getting-the-arguments-passed-to-a-executable-using-wmic